# angular.js - update scope and template after jsonp request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a directive that loads some html code inside a  tag:

**directive:**

```
var appDirectives = angular.module("skdApp", ["offerServices"]);
appDirectives.directive("widget", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div ng-controller="OfferCtrl"><p>{{offer.price}}</p></div>';
  }
```

**service**
Besides, I'm using a service to fetch some json data

```
angular.module('offerServices', ['ngResource']).
  factory('Offer', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('url/offer.json', {},
      {
        get: {method: 'JSONP', params: {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}}
      }
    );
});
```

**controller**
The controller adds the received data to the scope

```
function OfferCtrl($scope, Offer) {
  $scope.offer = Offer.get();
}
```

Now I'm facing the following problem. By the time the template is being loaded, the json request is not finished yet. This results in showing the template with an empty string for {{offer.price}}.

I would need a way to update the template with the corresponding values, once the offerServices has received a response (i.e. the offerService response is available)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

How about using [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak)

> Description
>
> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.
>
> The directive can be applied to the  element, but typically a
>   fine-grained application is prefered in order to benefit from
>   progressive rendering of the browser view.

Comment: You could use this or ng-show. I've found with ng-cloak that if you have some non-model text in whatever you're trying to hide that it will still show that text, but with ng-show it does not.