# Trying to make a custom directive for ngTable, but I don't know how to re-render with updated data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngtable

I think all I need is way to re-render the table or something that accomplishes that fact once the clients have been loaded. I tried `$scope.$apply()` inside the directive but it complains that a $digest cycle is already happening. And I also tried the ngTableParams built-in `reload()` but it doesn't seem to do anything. Inside my directive, `data` starts off as an empty array, but then is populated with about 20 items shortly after. It just won't show those updated results.

---

```
<div class="row">
    <j-table data="clients" search="search" class="table small-8 columns end">
        <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'last'">
            <span>{{client.first || 'no name'}}</span>
            <span>{{client.last || ''}}</span>
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Address'" sortable="'city'">{{client | formatAddress}}</td>
    </j-table>
</div>
```

---

```
angular.module('locqusAngular').directive('jTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            search: '='
        },
        template:
            '<table ng-table="tableParams"> \
                <tr ng-repeat="d in $data | filter:search.term"> \
                    <div ng-transclude></div> \
                </tr> \
            </table>',
        controller: function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10,
                sorting: {
                    name: 'asc',
                    filter: $scope.search
                },
                filter: {}
            }, {
                total: $scope.data.length,
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) : $scope.data;
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }
            });

            $scope.$watch('data.length', function(newx, oldx) {
                if (newx != null && newx !== oldx && newx > 0) {
                    $scope.tableParams.reload();
                }
            });
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Read the first and last line of the paragraph I wrote.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458935/angular-directive-template-update-on-data-load

Comment: I am trying to write exactly the same kind of directive wrapping ng-table. However, I am not getting any luck even trying to do exactly what you do. Did this work for you? Cheers.